# Static library needs MD_DynamicRelease

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I use 2 statically linked libraries in my project.
For some reason one of them needs the `RuntimeLibrary` value `MD_DynamicRelease`.
The other one needs `MT_StaticRelease`. 
This creates a conflict in my project. 
When I compile with `/MT`:
[image]

When I compile with `/MD`:
[image]

Do I need to compile my project differently? Do I need to compile the libraries differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to change the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE values to the right runtime libraries.